# Valid Object Constructors

Tags: javascript

which of the following are valid object constructors?

```
1) var m = function(){}
2) m = function(){}
3) m.prototype.constructor = function(){}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: if `firebug` or any `web consoles` did not display any error, then all of that are valid.. did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all appear to be valid statements that declare an empty function, and assign it to different variables.

Every function in Javascript is both an object itself (or f.prototype wouldn't work) and a potential object constructor.  Any function may be called with the `new Thingy` syntax (or perhaps `new m` in your example).  Or it could be called normally - the only special thing `new` does is set `this` to an object derived from f.prototype.

A newly created function has a `prototype` property that contains a newly minted object (`{}`), which has no properties except a hidden `constructor` property pointing at the function (it's a circular reference, actually)

It should be true that:

```
var m = function(){};
m.prototype.constructor == m;
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `var m = {};`

This is called an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

1) `var m = function(){}`

2) `m = function(){}`

Are almost same except the first one creates a local scoped function, the second - global. And in order to create an object you can just

```
var obj = new m();
```